# Calculate the number of atoms of oxygen present in 1.3 mol of sulfuric acid

Tags: stoichiometry, atoms, mole

> Calculate the number of atoms of oxygen present in $\pu{1.3 mol}$ of $\ce{H_2SO_4}$

1 mol has $6.02\times 10^{23}$ atoms

So $\pu{1.3 mol}$ must have $1.3 \times 6.02 \times 10^{23} = 7.826 \times 10^{23}$ atoms

---

Since there are 4 oxygen atoms  out of 7 atoms in total in $\ce{H_2SO_4}$,

${4 \over 7} \times 7.826 \times10^{23}$

So there are $4.472 \times 10^{23}$ oxygen atoms present.

However the answer key says that $3.1 \times 10^{24}$ atoms is the answer.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key about the unit *mole* is that it does not reference which type of entity is specified. Using the mole only makes sense if you define what you are using the mole for. This could be:

- protons
- atoms
- ions
- molecules
- formula units of an ionic or metallic solid
- aggregates
- apples
- stars
- …

The mole is basically just a large number that you can use instead of e.g. the number 1,000,000 or the number 0.5.

So in your question, $\pu{1.3 mol}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$ means that you have $1.3 \times 6.022 \times 10^{23}$ *molecules* of $\ce{H2SO4}$, each of which contains one sulphur atom, two hydrogen atoms and four oxygen atoms. Thus, in one mole of $\ce{H2SO4}$ you can find:

- $\pu{2mol}$ of hydrogen atoms
- $\pu{1mol}$ of sulphur atoms
- $\pu{50 mol}$ of protons
- $\pu{50mol}$ of electrons
- and $\pu{4mol}$ of oxygen atoms.

The correct solution is thus:

$$n(\ce{O}) = 4\times n(\ce{H2SO4}) = 4 \times 1.3 \times 6.022\times 10^{23} = 3.13 \times 10^{24}$$

Comment: Does 50 moles proton means 50 x 6,022 10^23 units of protons?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Not *units of protons*, individual protons. Protons are countable and a mole is essentially just a shorthand for *big number.*

Answer (score 6):

There are 1.3 mol of the entire acid molecule, so there are four as many moles of oxygen as there are of the acid, because one acid contains four oxygens.

$4×1.3=5.2$ and 5.2 times Avogadro's constant is (about) $3.1×10^{24}$ atoms.

Your error is in dividing by seven, which is neither conceptually nor mathematically correct.